# CSS layout for "2 columns + em-width separator in the middle"

Tags: css, layout

How to get the following layout using HTML + CSS:

```
|                        |x|                          |
|                        |x|                          |
```

All three columns (two columns and separator) should be *touching*, i.e. their background colors have to be touching without any gaps.

The problem I have with creating such layout is that I want the "separator" to have width measured in **em** (i.e. *font-width based*), while main contents columns are to fit the rest of width of encompassing element (i.e. *around 50%*).  I want this layout preserved, without the separator overlying left or right contents columns independently on font size (i.e. layout should be preserved if I increase or decrease font width).

Note that this layout is inside other container, and these containers can be repeated in the page.  Because of this I was not able to use any absolute-positioning solution.

Also container *should not use fixed width*: think of it as container having `width: 100%;` or `width: auto;` (or unset width).

Bonus points if the layout can be created with either left or right column missing (i.e. empty column).

Comment: This may not help you as it is a proposed part of CSS3, but what you want (and more) is part of the proposal.  It is specifically meant to handle cases like `div { width: calc(50%/2 - 0.5em); }`

[CSS 3 calc](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc)

Comment: Why you need the separator to be measured in ems?

Answer (score 5):

One possibility:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div> Column A </div>
    <div> Column B </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    overflow: auto;
}

.container > * {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;        
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container > :first-child {
    border-right: 0.5em solid COLOR;
}

.container > :last-child {
    border-left: 0.5em solid COLOR;
}
```

where `COLOR` is the color of the background-color of the separator column.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/3XHSu/show/

Comment: altought I really like this, I must point out that having a border on a div that has %width, makes the div get a width of %+border so your entire div will be 50%+0.5em in this example. The bordered div should be a child of the div instead of the div itself.

Comment: @Ben Have you noticed the `box-sizing` property in my code? It removes that issue... (the DIV is `50%` wide regardless of how wide the border is).

Comment: Nice idea. However, I believe the `box-sizing` property is not supported below IE8, so if that is a concern for Jakub this may not be a good choice. If it is not a concern, then great.

Comment: @Scott According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Box-sizing), it is supported in IE8.

Comment: Right. I said "below" IE8 (that is, IE6 and 7). This may not be a concern of his, but then again, it may be. That was the only reason I pointed it out.

Comment: The separator has to be a real box, not faked using border for left and right columns.  It is to provide leading line from height of one column to other in side-by-side diff.

Answer (score 5):

Using the `inline-block`s you could create a lot of different non-trivial layouts.

I've made two examples, the first, with the faux equal heights: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/nMWcG/

And the second variant, with the physical gap separator: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/nMWcG/5/

They are somewhat different (and there could be even more layouts based on the `inline-block`s that solve your problem), hope at least one of them would work for you :)

The whole idea is to use the `white-space: nowrap` on wrapper, so the columns won't drop if the sum of their widths is greater than wrappers' and then add a padding on a wrapper with a `width: auto` that would be equal to the desired gap.

If you'll need only one column, you could have one of the columns empty (without the `.column-content`), or remove them and have an extra class on them. Well, it depends on how you want the lonely column to behave etc.

Comment: What I want to use separator for is to provide leading lines from one height to other for side-by-side diff.  So it really needs to be there, but it cannot have height set, I don't think.

Comment: The separator *needs* a height to "be there". I think you can weave those diff lines into my solution. Thank you for the bounty.

Answer (score 5):

You can *always* use absolute positioning, but you need to **position the common ancestor as well** (`relative`).  Flexible multi-column layouts can be done best with floats:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>CSS Test Case: 2-Column Layout with Separator</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      .container {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        background-color: green;
      }

      .container .left {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
        background-color: red;
      }

      .container .left .padding {
        margin-right: 5em;
      }

      .container .right {
        float: right;
        width: 50%;
        background-color: fuchsia;
      }

      .container .right .padding {
        margin-left: 5em;
      }

      .container .separator {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 0;
        width: 10em;
        height: 100%;
        margin-left: -5em;
        background-color: blue;
      }

      div.clearBoth {
        clear: both;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 0;
        line-height: 0;
        font-size: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>CSS Test Case: 2-Column Layout with Separator</h1>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="left">
        <div class="padding">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam nulla dolor, tempor ac sollicitudin malesuada, tempus in metus. Nulla eget augue ut velit ullamcorper aliquam. Aliquam in nibh eu arcu tincidunt eleifend et ac justo. Donec mauris orci, tristique et ornare quis, dictum a ante. Suspendisse rhoncus commodo ligula, ac mattis eros dignissim vitae. Morbi pulvinar ultrices aliquam. Praesent tempus velit justo, eget fringilla leo. Aliquam fringilla risus eget justo ornare pellentesque. Duis ullamcorper scelerisque mauris vitae blandit. Morbi et bibendum orci. Sed vestibulum posuere nisi, vitae rhoncus mi laoreet in. Quisque commodo porttitor risus, id ullamcorper libero gravida at. Donec interdum accumsan blandit. Vestibulum ac eros et nisl fermentum cursus. Integer vitae ornare orci. Vestibulum facilisis adipiscing metus a suscipit.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <div class="padding">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam nulla dolor, tempor ac sollicitudin malesuada, tempus in metus. Nulla eget augue ut velit ullamcorper aliquam. Aliquam in nibh eu arcu tincidunt eleifend et ac justo. Donec mauris orci, tristique et ornare quis, dictum a ante. Suspendisse rhoncus commodo ligula, ac mattis eros dignissim vitae. Morbi pulvinar ultrices aliquam. Praesent tempus velit justo, eget fringilla leo. Aliquam fringilla risus eget justo ornare pellentesque. Duis ullamcorper scelerisque mauris vitae blandit. Morbi et bibendum orci. Sed vestibulum posuere nisi, vitae rhoncus mi laoreet in. Quisque commodo porttitor risus, id ullamcorper libero gravida at. Donec interdum accumsan blandit. Vestibulum ac eros et nisl fermentum cursus. Integer vitae ornare orci. Vestibulum facilisis adipiscing metus a suscipit.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="separator"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearBoth"><!-- clear --></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please notice that

- the background colors are touching as you can see no horizontal green (but see below);
- container dimensions are irrelevant (it works with any viewport size and any text content; but see below);
- it works with any font size;
- it works with any separator width, provided you adjust the margins as well (see below);
- it works anywhere, and several times, in a document because it uses CSS classes, not IDs;
- it works if you set `display: none` on the left column, the right column, or both.  As a result, it works if the left column, the right column, or both, are missing from the markup;
- it uses a minimum set of selectors, properties, and property values, that are all available since [CSS1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/) or [CSS2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/).

Because of the latter, it should also work in all CSS2-capable browsers as it does not rely on any UA-specific implementation.  I have tested this positive in the following browsers:

- Microsoft Internet Explorer 9.0.8112.16421 for Windows 7
- Google Chrome 16.0.912.41 beta for Debian GNU/Linux
- Google Chrome 15.0.874.121 m for Windows
- Chromium 14.0.835.202 (Developer Build 103287 Linux) Built on Debian unstable, running on Debian 6.0.3
- Mozilla Firefox 8.0.1 for Windows (on [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/))
- Iceweasel (Debian Firefox) 8.0
- Mozilla Firefox 7.0.1 for Windows (on Wine)
- Mozilla Firefox 6.0.2 for Windows (on Wine)
- Mozilla Firefox 5.0 for Windows (on Wine)
- Mozilla Firefox 4.0.1 for Windows (on Wine)
- Mozilla Firefox 3.6.24 for Windows (on Wine)
- Mozilla Firefox 3.5.19 for Windows (on Wine)
- Mozilla Firefox 3.0.19 for Windows (on Wine)
- Iceape (Debian SeaMonkey) 2.0.14
- Apple Safari 5.0.2 (7533.18.5) for Windows (on Wine)
- Apple Safari 4.0.5 (531.22.7) for Windows (on Wine)
- Opera 11.52.1100 for Linux
- Konqueror 4.6.5 for GNU/Linux (on KDE 4.6.5)
- Google Android 2.3.4 Browser
- Dolphin Browser HD 7.1.0 for Android
- Mozilla Firefox 8.0 for Android
- Opera Mobile 11.50 for Android
- Apple Mobile Safari 5.0.2 (6533.18.5) on iOS 4.2.1 (8C148) on iPhone 3G (MB496FD)

It does *not* work in:

- Mozilla Firefox 2.0 for Windows (on Wine): Floats are not supported.
- Mozilla Firefox 1.5.0.12 for Windows (on Wine): Floats are not supported.
- Mozilla Firefox 1.0.8 for Windows (on Wine): Floats are not supported.
- Microsoft Internet Explorer 6.0.2800.1106 for Windows 98 (on Wine): The separator is not always displayed, and if the viewport width changes, the layout falls apart.  Probably you can work around this with a stylesheet triggered by [Conditional Comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx).  (See also tereško's answer.)

[Test case](http://PointedEars.de/styles/test/columns2-with-separator)

Explanation:

1. With floats, you can have columns of 50% width, but you cannot have horizontal margins or paddings on them, because in the W3C (standard) CSS box model the box width equals the `width` plus horizontal padding.  So any (horizontal) paddings must be created by child elements.
2. In order to have the content of a column end at the separator box's boundaries, you need `margin-right` and `margin-left` for the child (`DIV`) elements within the left and right column half the `width` of the separator (`5em`), respectively.  `padding-right` and `padding-left` might work as well if no further `width` is involved.
3. In order to position the separator `absolute` between the left and right column, the container must be positioned `relative`. The separator has a negative margin (`margin-left: -5em`) so that its box shifts left half its `width: 10em` from the middle (`left: 50%`).
4. The container must `float: left` so that it provides the stacking context for the separator to be displayed on top of the columns (and to always have the correct width).  Therefore, you need `clear: left` before and `clear: both` after the container (the latter with a zero-height `DIV` element here).

Caveats:

1. If the height of the left and right columns differ, you will see vertical green. Use the usual tricks to emulate equal height. (See also tereško's answer.)
2. If the viewport grows shallower, content in the columns may overflow horizontally if it cannot be wrapped; especially replaced inline elements like images, and long words.  Declare an [`overflow` or `overflow-x` value](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#overflow) different from the default (`visible`) to prevent that.

**Update**: Validates as HTML 4.01 Strict and CSS2 now; clearing `BR` as child of `BODY`, and `magenta` color name did not, respectively.  Also, the `position` property was introduced with CSS2.

Answer (score 3):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xml:lang="en">
  <head> <title>CASH REGISTER</title>
  <style type="text/css">
        @media all {
        body              { margin:0 ; padding:0 ; background:#000000 ; color:white }
        div               { margin:0 ; padding:0  ; font-size:2em       }
        }
  </style >
  </head>
  <body>
<div style="background-color: #888 ; width: 51em">
<div style="background-color:red;float:left;width:25em">1</div>
<div style="background-color:green;float:left;width:1em">2</div>
<div style="background-color:blue;float:left;width:25em">3</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tried with font-size 1em also - then it shrinks all over to half the proportions ...

Comment: Left and right are to fill whole encompassing container.  **Explicit widths** for all (container, left, right) is not what I want to see.

Comment: This is not even remotely related to the question : -1

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/gjQVW/4/

```
<div class="container">
    <div>left</div>
    <div>right</div>
    <!--div>3rd</div>
    <div>4th</div-->
</div>
```

With these styles

```
.container {display: table; width: 100%; margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0; margin-top: 3em; background: red}

.container > DIV {border: 1px dashed red; display: table-cell; width: 1%; border-left: 0.5em solid black; border-right: 0.5em solid red; background: yellow}
.container > DIV:first-child {background: pink; border-left: 1px solid lime}
.container > DIV:last-child {background: teal; border-right: 1px solid yellow}
```

Using `display: table` and `table-cell` lets you have both columns keep the same height and make sure they are one right next to the other. You also are able to add more columns or just leave 1. You might need to tweak the `width: 1%`. For only two columns 50% should suffice, but as you add columns you have to start lowering it to keep the columns the same width, etc. You can also use `padding` for the separator, but `margin` and `table-cell` don't get along.

Also note that `:last-child` css selector is not supported in IE 8 and you'll need to use class or id on the column DIVs.

EDIT: Added another fiddle to cover the DIV that needs to be in the middle, since it needs to hold somecontent

http://jsfiddle.net/frozenkoi/RfzWb/
HTML:

```
<div class="mightyContainer">
    <div class="container3">
        <div>lefty<br><br><br>more lefty</div>
        <div class="divider">i</div>
        <div>right</div>
        <!--div>3rd</div>
        <div>4th</div-->
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.mightyContainer {position: relative; background: magenta; margin-top: 3em}
.container3 {display: table; width: 100%; margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0; background: red; -k-position: relative}

.container3 > DIV {border: 1px dashed red; display: table-cell; width: 50%; border-left: 0.5em solid yellow; border-right: 0.5em solid black; background: yellow}
.container3 > DIV:first-child {background: pink; border-left: 1px solid lime}
.container3 > DIV:last-child {background: teal; border-right: 1px solid yellow}
.container3 .divider {text-align: center; width: 1em; background: lime; border: none; opacity: 0.5;
    display: block; position: absolute; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; left: 50%; margin-left: -0.5em; /*height: 100%*/;
}
```

The separator is positioned in the middle with absolute positioning. Note that the additional DIV with the `mightyContainer` class is necessary because in FireFox the DIV with `divider` class uses the whole page as the parent for positioning instead of the `conteiner3`. RockMelt (webkit) and IE 8/9 didn't seem to need it if you move the styles from .mightyContainer to .container3 and remove the mightyContainer DIV (for an example of how FireFox behaves without that extra DIV see http://jsfiddle.net/frozenkoi/3zhsv/).

Comment: The separator really needs to be there, and not only faked using borders.  Nice trick using **display: table**.

Comment: @JakubNarębski Do you mean you need to have a DIV for the separator?

Comment: Added some extra stuff to handle that case, I didn't realize until now that the divider needed to hold content.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with combination of `:after` & `text-indent`. It's work till `IE8` for `IE7` & below you can use `css :after hack` http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/. In this example i didn't use hack for `IE7` for if you want you can use.

check this:

### http://jsfiddle.net/3XHSu/4/

**OR**

For modern browsers you can use `css3`  `box-flex` property there is no need to define `width:50%`
Check this:

### http://jsfiddle.net/XMg2h/2/

Answer (score 3):

Assuming i understood you right:

- simple ***fluid-fixed-fluid*** layout: **http://www.webdevout.net/test?0v&raw** 
   To view source click [here](http://www.webdevout.net/test?0v).
- with ability to remove either `<div class="left">` or `<div class="right">`, or *both*, try this link: **http://www.webdevout.net/test?0w&raw** ( imho, it has the feel of ugly hack , but works ). 
   To view source click [here](http://www.webdevout.net/test?0v)

The basic idea is this:

1. you take a 50-50% floated layout
2. stick a fixed width element `<div class="main">` between sides
3. adjust both initial elements, so that they use less space then before

As for ability to remove `right` side - it works in the original version, but to remove `left` side, there is require a placeholder `<div class="fix">`, which takes up the space, because all the elements are floated and page would collapse otherwise.

P.S. the `fluid-fixed-fluid` layout is sometimes affectionately called: **the unholy grail**.

P.P.S the layout might have the [3px gap bug](http://haslayout.net/css/3px-Gap-Bug-aka-Text-Jog-Bug) on IE6 (but i am not sure about that .. the *ie6fix.css* file was in the folder, but it was not included in the original testcase).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you expect equal height columns (there are plenty of places that talk about that if you want to implement them), but this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TNpnh/11/ shows some variations. This avoids Sime's `box-sizing` if IE7 and lower is needing to be supported. The basic structure is:

HTML

```
<div class="container">     
    <div class="LC"> Left </div> 
    <div class="RC"> Right<br/>Taller </div> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    padding: 0 0 0 1em; /*this creates the extra space */
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 10px 0; 
}


.container .LC {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 -1em; /* this allows all to fit */
    float: left;
    background-color: yellow;
    border-right: 1em solid blue;
}

.container .RC {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    background-color: cyan;
    border-left: 1em solid blue; /* this is duplicated so it fills the tallest column */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I really hope this would help you http://jsfiddle.net/EzfAs/

Comment: That is completely opposite to what was asked for.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go - http://jsfiddle.net/wbednarski/w97ax/5/

Solution works with one column as well. The trick is in the .separator class.